# How to skip "0" from a for() statement

Tags: c#, for-loop

How do i skip the number 0 (zero) from this for() statement. I want 0 to be skipped after -1.

```
 for(x=min_values; x<= max_values; x++)
 {

 }
```

my aim is to select every number between two textboxes called max and min. I am trying to plot a y = 1/x function. However when 0 is selected because there can not be 1/0 the program does not work.

Comment: `if (x == 0)continue;`

Comment: @HimBromBeere presumably there are negative values of `i` that must be handled.

Comment: i tried that @wkl

Comment: Use a numbering system that doesn't have a zero in it.

Comment: @Umutumut What was wrong with it?

Comment: @Umutumut then why didn't you put that in your question? Why haven't you provided ranges that `min_values` and `max_values` can be? Don't leave it up to people to guess.

Comment: is there really any point of down-voting this question?

Comment: We need much more information and explanation in order to be able to be helpful. What is `min_values`? What is `max_values`? Only skip `0` if it follows a `-1`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder look my aim is to select every number between two textboxes called max and min. I am trying to plot a y = 1/x function. However when 0 is selected because there can not be 1/0 the program does not work.

Comment: So validate if the value is `> 0` and perform your logic? What's the problem here?

Comment: Umutumut: @wkl's solution should work for that. You don't need to only skip 0 when it's after -1.

Answer (score 4):

The 'continue' keyword would accomplish what you're asking given the right logical condition. The example code you gave doesn't say what mix_values or max_values is.

```
for(int x = mix_values; x <= max_values; x++ ) {
     if( x == 0 ) { continue; }
     // ...the rest of your loop body logic goes here...
}
```

I'm assuming 0 would always come after -1 (if min_values < -1) given x++.

Comment: *"I'm assuming 0 comes after -1 in all cases given x++."* Well, not if `min_values` is 0. ;-) But the further comments from the OP show us that he's mistaken about only wanting to skip 0 after -1; from what he's said, he always wants to skip 0, which this does correctly.

Comment: Another reason specifics are important! Working under too many assumptions!! :-)

Comment: Big time. .....

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the `for`  :

```
if (x == 0 && lastMinValue  == -1 ){
      continue;
       }
int lastMinValue = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `min_values` may be negative. You've said:

> I want 0 to be skipped after -1.

In that case, just increment `x` at the end of the loop body when it's -1:

```
for(x=min_values; x<= max_values; x++)
{
    // ...loop body here, then:
    if (x == -1) {
       ++x;
    }
}
```

After that increment, the one in the `for` loop will kick in and the next `x` will be `1`.

I won't have any effect if `min_values` is `0`, because you said you wanted to skip `0` **after** `-1`, suggesting some kind of dependent relationship.

Example [in C# on IDEone](http://ideone.com/K3Kivw), and here in JavaScript, which *in this case* (not generally) works the same way as C#:

```js
var min_values = -2;
var max_values = 2;
var x;
for (x = min_values; x <= max_values; x++) {
  console.log(x);
  if (x == -1) {
    ++x;
  }
}
```

---

Of course, if you just wanted to skip `0`, you'd do what was suggested in a comment that you said didn't work:

```
for(x=min_values; x<= max_values; x++)
{
    if (x == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    // ...loop body here
}
```

...because it *does* work: Example [in C# on IDEone](http://ideone.com/HKbZ1Y) or, again, here in JavaScript as it happens to work the same way in this regard:

```js
var min_values = -2;
var max_values = 2;
var x;
for (x = min_values; x <= max_values; x++) {
  if (x == 0) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
```